# chop() vs rtrim()

Tags: php

I'm confused with PHP functions `rtrim()` and `chop()`, as they work similar and give similar output. Why are there different functions for trimming  trailing characters?

Sample examples:

**PHP**

```
$str = "Hello World!";
echo $str . "<br>";
echo rtrim($str,"World!") . "<br>"; //Hello
echo chop($str,"World!") . "<br>";  //Hello
```

Are there any differences between `chop()` and `rtrim()` functions?

Comment: Simple: http://php.net/manual/en/function.chop.php NO! `This function is an alias of: rtrim().`

Comment: @Rizier123 My question is why different function is there for similar work?

Comment: why? because they like too too too much stuffing php bundle with unneeded silly functions and/or aliasing them...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is also in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/aliases.php

And a quote from there:

> However there are functions which changed names because of an API cleanup or some other reason and the **old names are only kept as aliases for backward compatibility**.

And `chop()` is just a alias for `rtrim()` so they do the same. This is also in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.chop.php

A quote from there:

> This function is an alias of: rtrim().

Comment: What is meaning of `(PHP 4, PHP 5)` in both function `rtrim()` and `chop()`?

Comment: @Sadikhasan That the functions are wroking in these php versions

Comment: That means both function are implemented in `PHP 4 and PHP 5`.

Comment: @Sadikhasan You got it

Comment: One more question : before `PHP 4` there is no `rtrim() and chop()` function?

Comment: @Sadikhasan I wouldn't know about it

Comment: You say `That the functions are wroking in these php versions` that means before that these functions are not working.

Comment: @Sadikhasan Yep, as far as i know otherwise i wouldn't know about it

Answer (score 4):

As you can read in [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chop.php):

```
chop — Alias of rtrim()
```

Comment: I know `chop` is an alias of `rtrim()` but question is why different function for similar work? Is there any perfomance or execution difference?

Comment: An alias is just a different name for the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP for historic reasons there are some Functions which do the same.

Some of them has been deprecated. Some of them are still there.

split and preg_split is another example although both are working a little bit different (which isn't the case if a function is an alias for another one)

Answer (score 1):

Others have answered *why* there are two functions doing the same thing.

**However**:

> Is there any difference between chop and rtrim function?

Yes there is a difference!

In terms of **functionality** there is (currently) no difference. They will both (currently) work the same as one is simply an *alias* of the other.

**However**, note what else [PHP.net states](http://php.net/manual/en/aliases.php):

> It is usually a bad idea to use these kind of aliases, as they may be
>   bound to obsolescence or renaming, which will lead to unportable
>   script.

**The difference** is one is an older function retained for backwards compatibility.
This is not being pedantic. As with any changes in PHP (e.g. `mysql_` functions being depreciated), if you have a choice, you should use the most up to date one.

It's possible the alias may be removed in a future version of PHP, or the alias no longer maintained and so you lose out on improvements made to the newer function.